# How to display a string on the console?

Tags: java, console

Given a string value, how can I display it on the screen in my console? What do I have to write to make that happen?

As an example, this is the code I have so far:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "I am a school student and just started learning Java.";
        // What to write next?
    }
}
```

It works, but it obviously does not display the value on the console yet. What do I have to write to show it?

---

I want it to look something like this:
[image]

But all I get is this:

[image]

Comment: Please grab a decent Java tutorial and work your way through this. Printing strings to the console and other basic stuff should be covered very early.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah.. I should check out the tutorials. Thanks anyway. ^^

Comment: Surprising that nobody found a duplicate for something as simple as a **Hello World** program yet. If there is none, this could be a good addition to SOs general repository.

Comment: I was also surprised too.  Which why I created a Community Wiki answer.  Mind you, this question doesn't ask how to write a "hello world" program ... and when asked like this (^^^) it is clear that a "hello world" example does not really fit the bill as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, a Java program doesn't print anything.  You need to explicitly tell your program to print output.  Here are some of the ways that you can do that:

1. To print a String to standard output:

```java
System.out.print(message);
```

2. To print a String followed by a (platform appropriate) line separator:

```java
System.out.println(message);
```

3. To print a String to the standard error stream:

```java
System.err.print(message);
```

4. To print to the console (e.g. if standard output could have been redirected to a file):

```java
Console console = System.console();
if (console != null) { // Note that in some contexts there
                       // is not a usable `Console`...
    console.writer().print(message);
}
```

Note that the above `print` and `println` methods are defined by the `PrintWriter` class.  There are convenience overloads for all of the primitive types, and also for `Object`. In the latter case, what is printed is the result of calling `toString()` on the argument.

There are also `printf` methods for formatting a number of arguments according to a *format* string.

---

For more information, read the following:

- The javadocs for [`java.lang.System`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html), [`java.io.PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and [`java.io.Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html).
- [Oracle Java Tutorials: The Hello World Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print(message);
// or
System.out.println(message); // creates a new line after print is done.
```

There are many great courses on YouTube or the web for free which cover all basics and also intermediate topics.

Surf the internet about a problem before asking here. I'm not telling you that you can't ask here but you should put some effort into researching before asking.